# Ответ на WebRequest.Get

Tags: c#, .net, unity3d

Разрабатываю приложение на Unity3d для платформы WEBGL, и на данный момент мне нужно написать сервер. Мне надо чтобы приложение при старте получало строку с сервера, потом по ходу работы несколько раз (когда захочет пользователь) уже отправляла строку на сервер.
Так как tcpClient/listener'ы не работают (?) на WEBGL, придется использовать www или webrequest классы. Я знаю как отправлять GET/POST запросы клиента через webrequest, но не знаю как слушать и получать эти запросы на сервере. Сервер пишется на .net (консолька или forms). 
Вопрос: как слушать поступающие запросы? С tcpListener допустим мы в параллельном потоке в цикле слушаем, а тут как? Какие классы использовать? Допустим, клиент отправил GET запрос на сервер, сервер должен проверить заголовки, и если все правильно, отправить ответ (строку).
Спасибо.

Comment: `Так как tcpClient/listener'ы не работают (?) на WEBGL` вы сервер на web gl поднимать собрались? [Первое, что гуглится](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest.html) чем не устраивает?

Comment: Нет, про listener я просто так написал. Сервер - обычная консолька или Forms проект.

Comment: 1) Удалите все лишнее из вопроса, чтобы это был не поток мыслей, а вопрос 2) Опишите, что вы пробовали и что было не так с теми инструментами, что вы пробовали.

Comment: 1. Попробую
2. Сервер я не начал писать, потому что не знаю как принимать GET запросы, поэтому и задал вопрос.

Comment: Для сервера используйте asp.net - можете выбрать что из него использовать, например asp.net MVC, asp.net WEB API, asp.net core - любое из этого может принимать и обрабатывать http get запросы

Comment: Если сервер - обычная консолька, то я бы порекомендовал поглядеть в сторону asp.net core - оно и хоститься в консоли умеет, и под линуксами если надо можно запустить. Вот вам ссылка на туториал [Build web APIs with ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: Ясно. Т.е. без ASP все таки не обойтись. Ну ладно, спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Без asp.net обойтись можно, можно сервер на HttpListener написать или сразу на ассемблере, если у вас бесконечное количество времени на реализацию